# События для динамически созданного компонента

Tags: delphi

Динамически создается компонент типа `TIdFTP`, вот так:

```
IdFTP1 := TIdFTP.Create;  

IdFTP1.Name := 'IdFTP1';  
IdFTP1.OnWork := FTPWork;  
IdFTP1.OnWorkBegin := FTPWorkBegin;  
IdFTP1.AutoLogin := True;  
IdFTP1.TransferType := ftBinary;  
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.ProxyType := fpcmNone;  
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Port := 0;  
IdFTP1.Passive:=True;  
IdFTP1.Host:=__host;  
IdFTP1.Port:=__port;  
IdFTP1.Username:=__user;  
IdFTP1.Password:=__pass;  
IdFTP1.Connect;
```

проблема в том, что при запуске приложения компилятор ругается на эти 2 строчки

```
IdFTP1.OnWork := FTPWork;  
IdFTP1.OnWorkBegin := FTPWorkBegin;
```

> [DCC Error] FtpManage.pas(39): E2009 Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'
>   [DCC Error] FtpManage.pas(40): E2009 Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'
>   [DCC Error] FtpManage.pas(92): E2096 Method identifier expected
>   [DCC Error] FtpManage.pas(98): E2096 Method identifier expected
>   [DCC Error] FtpManage.pas(99): E2096 Method identifier expected

процедуры `FTPWork` и `FTPWorkBegin` должным образом прописаны.

Почему не хочет нормально работать?

Comment: А можно всетаки показать декларацию

FTPWork и FTPWorkBegin

И заодно сообшение как компилятор ругается

Comment: interface  

procedure FTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);  
procedure FTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCountMax: Int64);  



implementation  

 procedure FTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);  
begin  
  TForm1.pb1.Position:=AWorkCount;  
end;  

procedure FTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;  
  AWorkCountMax: Int64);  
begin  
TForm1.pb1.Max:=  IdFTP1.Size(currentFile);  
TForm1.pb1.Position:=0;  
end;

Answer (score 3):

> 'method pointer and regular procedure'

Это значит, что компилятор ожидает получить указатель не на процедуру, а на метод класса.

Сделайте `FTPWork` и `FTPWorkBegin` методами формы.

Answer (score 2):

Введите  их в форму вот так

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdFTP1: TIdFTP;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdFTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  public
    procedure FTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
    procedure FTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
  end;
```

ну в public или в private сами решайте ))
ну и implementation соответственно так

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.FTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Свойство `OnWork` компонента `TIdFTP` имеет тип `TWorkEvent`, который является наследником типа `TNotifyEvent`. Зная это, можно присвоить данному свойству обработчик через тип `TMethod`:

```
procedure alert();   // наш псевдообработчик
begin
  showmessage('Текст =)');
end;

...
var
  eve: TMethod;
begin
  eve.Сode := @alert;  // вешаем наш обработчик
  eve.Data := nil;
  idftp1.OnWork := TWorkEvent(eve);  
end;
...
```

Далее, думаю, разберетесь. =)

Answer (score 2):

1.Проблема в том, что эти процедуры не есть методы объекта. А нужно чтобы они были методами какого-то объекта, например - формы.

```
TWorkEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; const AWorkCount: Integer) of object;
TWorkBeginEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; const AWorkCountMax: Integer) of object;
```

2.В указанных событиях параметры AWorkCount и AWorkCountMax - должны иметь тип Integer, а у вас Int64 (актуально для версий ниже Delphi 2009)

Comment: "В событиях AWorkCount и AWorkCountMax - Integer. А у вас Int64."

у вас версия Delphi старая В 2010 и выше Int64

Comment: Ок, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Integer - это, по сути, int32, так, что существенного изменения из-за этого не произойдет, @Vahan Av.

Comment: Эти процедуры находятся в отдельном модуле, который не имеет формы. Как сделать их методами формы.

Comment: Ну да

Но Пока не придет время мигрировать на XE2

Comment: Можно обработчик события держать на форме и из него вызывать ваши процедуры.

Comment: @Nofate  
Дело как раз в том. что надо эти процедуры держать в том же модуле где создается ФТП, а не в модуле формы... :(

Comment: @Dagmanor, как вариант, создайте класс где эти процедуры станут методами в том-же модуле. В `initialization` создавайте объект, а в `finalization` его уничтожайте.